# Component flickers after updated data found in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a React Native component where i'm calling for data in `useEffect` and rendering data accordingly. But i need to call for data after every 2 seconds and i'm doing that. But the whole component flickers after every two seconds. How can i stop that? Here's my component right now:

```js
   const Climate = () => {
   const rooms: ControllerRoom<ClimateRoomItemType>[] =
        useSelector(climateSelector);
    const displayRoomList = useSelector(displayRoomListSelector);

    //State
    const [active, setActive] = useState<number>(-1);
    const [count, setCount] = useState<number>(0);
    const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState<boolean>(true);

    //Handlers
    const fetchClimate = useCallback(
        () => dispatch(desktopAction.fetchClimate()),
        [dispatch],
    );
    
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        fetchClimate();
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    const fetchData = useCallback(
        () => {
            const interval = setInterval(() => {
                fetchClimate();
            }, 2000);
            return () => {
                fetchClimate();
                clearInterval(interval);
            };
        },[]
      );

    useEffect(() => {
        if (active < 0 && rooms.length > 0) {
            setActive(newlist[0][0].id);
            setIsFetching(false);
        }
    }, [rooms, isFetching]);
    
    return(
     <ControllerContainer>
           {!displayRoomList ? (
                        <RoomsClimate
                            key={Math. floor(Math. random() * 100)}
                            rooms={rooms}
                            displayRoomList={displayRoomList}
                        />
                    ) : null}
    </ControllerContainer>
    )
    }
    
    export default memo(Climate);
```

How can i stop flickering of component and still ask for data every 2 seconds?